# How to remove entire files and folders created for the nodejs and npm installation

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-10-desktop

I don't know what happend. All of a sudden, my nodeJS and npm started not responding and many errors popup and i reinstalled many times and not yet that works. When one problem solves, another rises. So i want to clean enitre setup files including in registery and other areas. Please someone help me.so i can reinstall node and npm.

Comment: Which OS you are using

Comment: Windows 10. I updated my lap to creators update. Can that be an issue?

Comment: I don't thing that will be the issue, Try to follow the answer instructions, may be that will help you to install it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove node from your window follow below instructions

1- Uninstall node from Programs & Features with the uninstaller.

2- Remove all the shortcuts like on task managers/ desktop etc

3-Reboot your system

4-Remove all the folder given below

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs
C:\Program Files\Nodejs
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc (and possibly check for that without the . prefix too)
```

5-Remove from the environment variable via checking Path value

6-Open your command prompt try to run below command

```
where node
```

If it will show directories then delete all the directories

7-Reboot your system

8-Go to the node js side download or directly install the node from there.